# How to use custom Authorize attribute in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET Core 2.0 project where I am using my custom Authroization logic by Implementing `AuthorizeAttribute` so when I am adding in startup.cs as below

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(Configuration, IBussinessAuthLogic));
});
```

But I want to enable specific endpoint for authorization but how can I pass an instance of the interface in using `[Authorize]`?

Comment: You should read a basic ASP.NET Core Authorization tutorial (the ones on Microsoft Docs are pretty good). You are not supposed, at all, to create a custom Authorize attribute. Create and apply policies instead.

Comment: Here is the documentation that shows you how to implement policy-based authorization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies

Comment: You need to register *policies* which you can then refer to with the authorize attribute.